# Spring Security and Tomcat 8 JSessionId response mismatch

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have webapp, which implements Java Security to distinguish users and admins. On the front end side i use Wicket to implement different actions and views for my pages. The whole login system works great, except one thing. If I deploy my app to a remote Tomcat ( The same version as in my local environment) and try to login as usual with the same username/password combination spring security redirects to my login page. I try to check the logs, and as I observed, in the remote Tomcat side my authentication method works fine, Spring successfully recognizes my credentials, and authorize me with the proper authority as "ROLE_USER", but somehow the session ID or the object, or something is lost, and Spring creates a new one with anonymous permissions, and then redirects back to login. As i noticed, the JSessionID in my localhost is the same when i request the form submit, and then the /user/home page, and in remote the ID's of the two requests are different. Is this means that Tomcat, or Apache doesn't support some of the Spring security's functionality, or I missed some config tags in my app?

**UPDATE**

In the google developer console I recognized, that firstly after form submit the request sent to the server. The application successfully authenticate the user, send back a JSessionID cookie with a http 302 status code. Thereafter the browser sent a GET request to the proper /user/home url, but without any cookie in the header, so that's why the spring security creates a new one, and send back to /login page?

**SOLUTION**

The problem was with the domain request forwarding. My domain eg. test.com forward my request to  test.com/myapp, and then it sends the response back with the proper cookie, but with path: "/myapp". Then the browser cannot recognize the requested URL, and doesn't send it back to the server. Spring security didn't find the appropiate JSessionID, and then it creates a new one, which cannot obtain from SecurityContextHolder. 
Zildyan answer was the best approach to the solution, so i will accept that.

My Web.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">
        <display-name>GAReporter</display-name>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>5000</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
        </session-config>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
          <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
          </listener-class>
        </listener> 
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>wicket.wicket-spring</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
                <param-value>com.carusselgroup.application.GAApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>wicket.wicket-spring</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Spring security

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xml

        ns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

                <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
                    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
                    <form-login login-page="/login" log

    in-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />


            <csrf disabled="true" />
    </ht

tp>

        <authentication-manager alias="
                authenticationManager ">
            <authentication-provider>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="SELECT username,password ,user_role.enabled
                                              FROM public.user 
                                              INNER JOIN user_role 
                                              ON public.user.user_id=user_role.user_id
                                              where public.user.username=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username,user_role.role
                                              FROM public.user 
                                              INNER JOIN user_role 
                                              ON public.user.user_id=user_role.user_id
                                              where public.user.username=?" />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
    </beans:beans>
```

LoginPage.java:

```
public class LoginPage extends WebPage
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6820791987770181938L;   

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomePage.class);

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize()
    {
        super.onInitialize();
        FeedbackPanel fbPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        add(fbPanel);
        StatelessForm<Void> form = new StatelessForm<Void>("form")
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8390180201075042069L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit()
            {
                SpringWicketWebSession session = SpringWicketWebSession.getSpringWicketWebSession();
                logger.info("Trying to login with: " + username + "\\" + password);
                if (session.signIn(username, password))
                {
                    logger.info("Login username/password authentication success: " + username + "\\" + password);
                    setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
                } else
                {
                    logger.info("Login username/password authentication failed: " + username + "\\" + password);
                    error("Sign in failed, Incorrect username or password");
                }
            }
        };
        form.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(this));
        form.add(new TextField<String>("username").setRequired(true));
        form.add(new PasswordTextField("password").setRequired(true));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

AuthenticatedWebSession class:

```
public class SpringWicketWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 779910029564267643L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SpringWicketWebSession.class);

    @SpringBean(name = "authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private HttpSession httpSession;

    Authentication authentication = null;

    public SpringWicketWebSession(Request request)
    {
        super(request);
        Injector.get().inject(this);

         ensureDependenciesNotNull();
    }

    public static SpringWicketWebSession getSpringWicketWebSession()
    {
        return (SpringWicketWebSession) Session.get();
    }

    private void ensureDependenciesNotNull()
    {
        if (authenticationManager == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Requires an authentication");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password)
    {
        logger.info("authentication starting...");
        boolean authenticated = false;
        try
        {
            authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            authenticated = authentication.isAuthenticated();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            logger.error("Authentication failed with");
            logger.error("Exception: " + e);
            authenticated = false;
        }
        return authenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public Roles getRoles()
    {
        Roles roles = new Roles();
        getRolesIfSignedIn(roles);
        return roles;
    }

    private void getRolesIfSignedIn(Roles roles)
    {
        if (isSignedIn())
        {
            addRolesFromAuthentication(roles, authentication);
        }
    }


    private void addRolesFromAuthentication(Roles roles, Authentication authentication)
    {
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities())
        {
            roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
    }
}
```

and the tomcat-spring logs:

```
2016-10-20 15:45:38,352 9380 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] INFO  com.carusselgroup.page.HomePage - Trying to login with: test\test
2016-10-20 15:45:38,352 9380 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] INFO  c.c.config.SpringWicketWebSession - authentication starting...
2016-10-20 15:45:38,352 9380 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,352 9380 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-10-20 15:45:38,358 9386 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
2016-10-20 15:45:38,359 9387 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT username,password ,user_role.enabled FROM public.user INNER JOIN user_role ON public.user.user_id=user_role.user_id where public.user.username=?]
2016-10-20 15:45:38,360 9388 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2016-10-20 15:45:38,360 9388 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/common__gareporter]
2016-10-20 15:45:38,375 9403 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-10-20 15:45:38,376 9404 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
2016-10-20 15:45:38,376 9404 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT username,user_role.role FROM public.user INNER JOIN user_role ON public.user.user_id=user_role.user_id where public.user.username=?]
2016-10-20 15:45:38,376 9404 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2016-10-20 15:45:38,376 9404 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/common__gareporter]
2016-10-20 15:45:38,383 9411 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-10-20 15:45:38,390 9418 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] INFO  com.carusselgroup.page.HomePage - Login username/password authentication success: test\test
2016-10-20 15:45:38,391 9419 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,393 9421 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,394 9422 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Page - ending request for page [Page class = com.carusselgroup.page.LoginPage, id = 0, render count = 0], request org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest@4fcc406b
2016-10-20 15:45:38,394 9422 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - 'http-nio-10467-exec-3' released lock to page with id '0'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,394 9422 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - 'http-nio-10467-exec-3' notifying blocked threads
2016-10-20 15:45:38,395 9423 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,395 9423 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,395 9423 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,395 9423 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,396 9424 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5776b12c
2016-10-20 15:45:38,396 9424 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@442b46a2: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442b46a2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3af765a
2016-10-20 15:45:38,396 9424 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
2016-10-20 15:45:38,397 9425 [http-nio-10467-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/user/home'; against '/logout'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /user/home' doesn't match 'POST /j_spring_security_check
2016-10-20 15:45:38,407 9435 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,408 9436 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,408 9436 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa93c2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffe21a: RemoteIpAddress: 10.1.0.45; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/user/home'; against '/user**'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/user/home'; against '/admin**'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-10-20 15:45:38,412 9440 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/home reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-10-20 15:45:38,413 9441 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,413 9441 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,413 9441 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,413 9441 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.r.m.CompoundRequestMapper - One compatible mapper found for URL 'user/home' -> 'Mapper: org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.MountedMapper; Score: 4'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,413 9441 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,422 9450 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,423 9451 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,423 9451 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,423 9451 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,423 9451 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/user/home'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,424 9452 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5776b12c
2016-10-20 15:45:38,424 9452 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-10-20 15:45:38,424 9452 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
2016-10-20 15:45:38,424 9452 [http-nio-10467-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-10-20 15:45:38,440 9468 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,440 9468 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
2016-10-20 15:45:38,440 9468 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /j_spring_security_check
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa93c2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffe21a: RemoteIpAddress: 10.1.0.45; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,441 9469 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/user**'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/admin**'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,442 9470 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.r.m.CompoundRequestMapper - One compatible mapper found for URL 'login' -> 'Mapper: org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.MountedMapper; Score: 2'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,443 9471 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.p.h.servlet.ServletWebRequest - Calculating context relative path from: context path '/GAReporter-1.0', filterPrefix '', uri '/GAReporter-1.0/login'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,444 9472 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - 'http-nio-10467-exec-5' attempting to acquire lock to page with id '0'
2016-10-20 15:45:38,444 9472 [http-nio-10467-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.w.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - http-nio-10467-exec-5 acquired lock to page 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I was facing that problem to. Thing was that cookie in my case could be sent only over https.
- next case was when I tried to reestablish user session after system restart/redeploy. Tomcat serialize all active user sessions and writes all attributest down and on system reboot deserialize them, and compare jsessionid to the one in cookie, but I was missing secureAuthId because tomcat did not remember it.